# triming records everything after 7 characters

Tags: trim, spaces, records

I am trying to remove/trim everything after 7 characters.

**issue #1** removing everything after 6 or 7 chracters
example: 1Q7 4B7  MY NAME IS MARY

Results I want: 1Q7 4B7

**issue #2** removing one space
example: EQ9  2IQ
Results I want: EQ9 2IQ

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: what language are we using here?

Comment: Oracle 10 and 11g, using Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

[SUBSTRING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, 6) AS MYCOLUMN FROM TABLE
```

Something like this should do the trick; you may have to fiddle with the numbers.

[More SUBSTR Examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

Comment: Issue #1 resolved ...Thank you :)      Can you assist in issue #2 plz.

Comment: This should work for either case. Read the documentation. The first param (1) says 'start at this character', the second param (6) says 'Give me this many characters from the start point'. You should be able to tweak this for both cases (in fact they should give you the same result either way.) Kindly accept the answer if it works for you.